# Get a new Array from an Object with multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, filter

I am getting a very big object from my API Endpoint back.
It is an object with multiple arrays. In each of them as an url  (items.[0].images[0].url for example). I would like  to create a new Array, just with the urls and store them in my Redux store.

I have tried to use a filter method, but I am getting back the same big Array every time, without any changes.

Furthermore, I notice if I
console.log(typeof res.data.items)  I am getting an object instead of an array as an output. I am a just confused, because my console is also saying res.data.items is an array.

**Thats a part of my res object**

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "/me/top/artists?limit=20&offset=11", method: "get", headers: {…}, baseURL:    "https://api.spotify.com/v1", transformRequest: Array(1), …}



data:
href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/artists?limit=20&offset=11"
items: Array(20)
0:
external_urls: {spotify: "https://open.spotify.com/artist/0fA0VVWsXO9YnASrzqfmYu"}
followers: {href: null, total: 4774667}
genres: (3) ["hip hop", "ohio hip hop", "rap"]
href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0fA0VVWsXO9YnASrzqfmYu"
id: "0fA0VVWsXO9YnASrzqfmYu"
images: Array(3)
     0:
         height: 640
          url: "https://i.scdn.co/image/4cb57ae1ef87546455db9cf65ba414c311ff459a"

1: {…}
2: {…}
```

....

**that's my function**

```
.then((res) => {
      ***let newdata = res.data.items.filter((url) => url.images[0].url)*** // not working

      console.log('newdata', newdata) // getting back res.data.items

      console.log(res.data.items) // Array
      console.log('res', res)
      console.log(typeof res.data.items) // Object ?
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_TOP_25_ALBUMS,
        payload: newdata,
      })
    })
```

Comment: you need to use **map** instead of **filter** in case you want to transform the array. Try using **res.data.items.map** instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.filter()` doesn't do what you think it does. Filter takes a "predicate", that is a function which takes an input and returns either `true` or `false`. It then applies that function to each array element and returns an array containing *only the elements where the predicate returned true*.

So in the case of

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].filter(item => item > 3)`

You would get a return value of `[4, 5]`, because only `4` and `5` return `true` when applied to the predicate `item => item > 3`

In your case your filter function is `res.data.items.filter((url) => url.images[0].url)`. Since your predicate is just *returning the value of the url field*, your predicate is always going to return `true` unless the url field is set to either

1. `undefined`
2. `null`
3. "" (an empty string)

That's almost certainly not the case in any of your data, so entire array is being returned.

What you are trying to do is take an array where each element has shape `X` and map it to an array where each element has shape `Y`. For this you need `.map()`

Try the following:

`res.data.items.map(item => item.images[0].url)`

This will take the contents of the `res.data.items` array, and replace each element with the return value of the function passed in when supplied with the value of that element.

Comment: Oh I got. Could you help my maybe with another thing I will updated my question in 1 minutes

Comment: @DanielRg If you have a different problem, you should create a new question

Comment: I have to wait 90 minutes that's the problem. But if I do not get an answer I will do that

Comment: @DanielRg I've just rejected your attempt to edit my answer. Stack Overflow answers are for answers to the question only. If you have a new question, please create a new question.

Comment: No problem :) if you wouldn't mind clicking the green tick next to my answer to indicate that its the accepted answer to your question that would be fab

Answer (score 1):

To create a new Array, you can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Try

```
let newdata = res.data.items.map(item => item.images[0].url)
```

Comment: Genius. Pleas don't say my mistake was to use url instead of item

Comment: No your mistake was to use filter instead of map